# What scares J.K. Rowling (her boggart)?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

Did J.K. Rowling ever reveal what scares her most? In other words, what form her boggart would take?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a matter of fact, she did (same interview she indicated what her Animagus form would be).

> **Q**: What shape would a Boggart take if it wanted to scare you? How would you defeat it?
>   **A: J.K. Rowling** responds: I think I'd probably have Aragog, as Ron did. I hate spiders.

Src: Transcript of J.K. Rowling’s live interview on Scholastic.com October 16, 2000

Comment: What about an eight-legged Viggo Mortensen (Aragorn son of Aragog)?

Comment: I also once saw confirmation in an interview that she thought Molly's Boggart (loved ones dead) was pretty scary too though.

Comment: @balancedmama - Indeed. See my answer.

Comment: @Keith wait, wasn't he Son of Arathorn?

Answer (score 12):

### Her Boggart changes over time, usually reflecting what she is currently writing.

**1970's - Scary librarians**

> **@nancy_whiskey: I'm not sure the inventor of Madame Pince could be taken down by a librarian's disapproving look!**
> **@jk_rowling:** *You're so wrong. She sprang directly from my childhood fear of scary librarians. The kind who hate kids.*
> <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/614141084034318336)</sub>

**1990's - Harry Potter being unpublished**

> **@givemhelldarlin What kept you motivated? Did you ever just feel like giving up at some point?**
> **@jk_rowling:** *I wasn't going to give up until every single publisher turned me down, but I often feared that would happen.*
> <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/713292055284424704)</sub>

**2000 - Giant spiders**

> **Question: What shape would a Boggart take if it wanted to scare you? How would you defeat it?**
> **J.K. Rowling responds:** *I think I'd probably have Aragog, as Ron did. I hate spiders.*
> <sub>["About the Books: transcript of J.K. Rowling's live interview on Scholastic.com," Scholastic.com, 16 October 2000](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-scholastic-chat.htm)</sub>

**2001 - Dementors**

> **Child: If you saw a Boggart, what would it change into and how would you destroy it?**
> **JKR:** *Erm ... either a spider, like Ron sees when his Boggart turns into a giant spider, possibly a Dementor, because I think they're the scariest things I've written.*
> <sub>[Blue Peter (cBBC), 12 March, 2001](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bluepeter.htm)</sub>

**2005 - Dead relatives / Being buried alive**

> **What would a Boggart turn into if you stood in front of one?**
>
> *The same thing Molly Weasley saw when she let a Boggart out of the locked cabinet in 'Order of the Phoenix' – my loved ones, dead. If, however, you are talking about a fear that concerns only me, it would be being buried alive. I'm not sure how a Boggart would represent that; perhaps turn into a coffin around me? Urgh.*
> <sub>[J.K. Rowling's old website - FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20110623034712/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=106)</sub>

**2014 - Forgetting Harry Potter details**

> **@jk_rowling:** *I had a waking nightmare where I met a Harry Potter fan who quizzed me on a sub-plot & I couldn't remember what I'd written*
> <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/508718414379356163)</sub>

**2016 - Public speaking**

> **@SeaBowmaster: what terrifies you JK?**
> **@jk_rowling:** *Public speaking. I agreed to read live at the opening ceremony of the 2012 Olympics in the belief that it would either kill or cure me.*
> <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/806542296732798976)</sub>